# Loop variable in node anchor specification

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

Given a loop variable `\x`, I would like to use it as `(foo.\x west)`, for example, where `\x` could be `north`.
My attempt:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {foo};
    \node[draw] (b) at (1,0) {bar};

    \draw[red]
        foreach \x in {north,south} {(a.\x west) -- (b.\x east)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This causes the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `northwest' (in 'northwest').
```

Unfortunately, `(a.\x\ west)` or `(a.\x{} west)` also does not work, then I get the `Missing \endcsname inserted` error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\space` right after your variable.

[image: space after variable]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {foo};
    \node[draw] (b) at (1,0) {bar};

    \draw[red]
        foreach \x in {north,south} {(a.\x\space west) -- (b.\x\space east)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```